How could I create a naming system for non-biological creatures in my book that makes sense to the reader and a character in-world?
I'm wondering how to create a naming system that makes sense both in-world and the reader.
The creatures I speak of come in various different forms/species. They're made of metal and can vary in what they have - some have energy cannons, others have wings and some have both, etc. Of course, these aren't the only characteristics, there are others such as armor thickness and size, but how would I effectively allow both a reader and a biologist in the world to know exactly which one I was talking about?
Coming from an engineering background, my first thought was with something similar to model numbers, but then I realized that a reader may not understand model numbers without a more in depth explanation which could be too technical. Every reference to such a creature is done from a technical manual within the world.
My first attempt like a model number:
NATIVE COUNTRY - # WINGS - # ENERGY CANNONS - ARMOR THICKNESS - etc.
My second thought was something like a binomial nomenclature like we have for animals, but it wouldn't communicate the major points that a person in my character's position would need to know (they disassemble these frequently). How would I go about this?

This sounds like a question that might be more suitable for the worldbuilding stackexchange site.

@Wyvern123 Doubt it would fly in Worldbuilding, VTCs for too-story-based because it's purely a culture/history sort of thing.

Are these creatures the characters? As in will they be referring to each other (and the narrative to them) by 'name' in the same way they would if they were people?

Write stories, not encyclopedias
Take a step back from world-building, and think about how the reader perceives the names as story information.
Consider Brandon Sanderson's first law of magic:

An author’s ability to solve conflict satisfactorily with magic is directly proportional to how well the reader understands said magic.

Do readers need to remember the individual species?
Is there some point in the story where these names matter?
Is there a conflict where the difference is crucial to understanding the plot?
If yes, your naming needs to be clear and easy – at least in the areas that matter so your characters can discuss the conflict and the reader can follow along without a chart. Make the plot-crucial names themselves as different as possible: different letters of the alphabet, different number of syllables, different sounds (phonemes) entirely.
Numbers anonymize
Model numbers are not the best way to create memorable names, in fact they probably do the opposite. They 'anonymize' the creatures.
Names like X-1 imply a one-of-a-kind eXperimental prototype.
An X-2 implies that there was an X-1 that exploded.
ED-209 and Starliner-3000 evoke a (retro/satyrical) consumerist world driven by product marketing and the latest models. Sequential numbering is implied but we are already many generations after the 1st model.
Names like C-3PO and R2-D2 evoke technobabble, and cryptic acronyms used by NASA and the military. It implies some technical function which would be above the layman anyway.
Names like Seven-of-Nine and Six are de-humanizing. We are never forgetting they are impersonal machines, however this is to contrast them with fully-human characters. There's no meaningful difference implied between the other numbers of their kind, on the contrary all the numbers are an implied collective with similar goals.
Wordplay, Texture, and Wallpaper
JK Rowling adds mini-loredumps to pad out her 700-word novels, involving trivia about someone with an amusingly fru-fru name that is a sort of a pun, or a play on words. These NPC are not meant to be plot-crucial or even remembered, rather they are 'texture' for her world-building.
On the downside, she gives main characters the same kinds of names, creating a wallpaper effect where everything is more of the same. A mythical name like Dumbledore sits along a mundane name like Ron – more of a subjective character-signal than objective world-building. (She's criticized for ethnic names, suggesting she stuck to an in-story feel-the-whimsy rule even though it went outside her vocabulary.)
Edward Gorey had 3 cousins named Rose Marshmary, Mary Rosemarsh, and Marsh Maryrose, a similar wordplay idea that deliberately makes them un-differentiated.
Con-lang and pseudo-taxonomy
You mention country of origin, suggesting allied factions which trade weaponry and manufacturing. It sounds important for a story where the revelation has political repercussions. But when if say Kingdom Zulag's drone is different from the B'mnebibi Alliance's drone, I'm not getting a clear picture. It's syllables like the texture/wallpaper above. I have to take your word for it.
Or you could code your names with pseudo-taxonomy, then re-enforce it by repeating the root-words, with or without an explanation for the reader.
prefix that implies an environment?
Fin – shallow water
Desi – deserts, dry
Avi – air, flight
Pola - ice, glacier
Arbori – tree
The idea is to use familiar base words or near wordplay to suggest something specific in the reader's head. The con-lang words aren't completely foreign or random. They have a loaded association.
In this case you are blurring machines with animals, so try tapping into the universal knowledge that readers already have.
suffix that suggests a body type?
cow, raptor, bear, tiger, snake, weasel, bug
bio-weaponry?
horned, spiked, billed, hoofed, fanged, plated, scaled
movement?
runner, jumper, hopper, glider, digger
sequential categories of a type?
Small, Medium, Large
alpha, beta, sigma
larva, pubescent, adult
A spiked desiraptor eating fincow larvae almost sounds like a real sentence. If you want to mix-in more machine ideas, add that kind of vocabulary to the word-pool.
Switch it up
Assuming your creatures come from different parts of the world, chances are they were discovered and named (or created from inspiration) by different societies with different ideologies and levels of technology.
Your engineer might be using colloquial words mixed with borrowed cultures' words mixed with engineering terms. Pull from a broad vocabulary if you want to invoke that big world.
A porcupine is literally a 'spiky pig' with a fancy accent. A simple transposed name like that is great when used sparingly, but a whole catalog of similar wordplay probably won't feel so clever. I suggest using your naming rules only as they actually appear in the story, or as they become relevant to the plot.
Decide what coded effect you want these names to carry. If they are unique and fantastical creatures, or if they are endless industrialized drones. Name the story-relevent ones first (presumably the fresher ideas), and leave plenty of implied iceberg unlabelled.

Assuming they're all made of the same metal we don't need to say anything about the material they're made of. If we're going for a coding system based on their features we don't particularly need regional distinctions so we can forget noting what country they come from.
Each code does need to note enough characteristics to differentiate the known species of creatures however once you have that no other characteristics actually matter. For example if all known species had 2 wings and 3 energy cannons then you wouldn't note those numbers at all, only points of difference. If there are many creatures with the same different numbers of wings and cannons but their armour varies then three numbers are all that is needed, have them in a set order or with a letter proceeding them to make it clear what each number represents.
For example we have W2C1A30, (a creature with 2 wings 1 cannon and 30mm of armour) W2C1A45 (similar but with heavier armour), these are easily differentiated from the W2C2A30 and W2C2A45 which have more firepower. Assuming everyone knows the order we can shorten these to 2-1-30, 2-1-45, 2-2-30, and 2-2-45. If these creatures also have variants that use or don't use, for example, energy shields then you'd need four numbers etc...
Work out what features need to be noted to split everyone up usefully, create a set order for those features, use letter prefixes if you feel they're necessary and you have an engineers' code book of incredible creatures. I'd suggest the following order minus those features that are irrelevant because they're either all the same or they done actually make a difference to the person who needs to know what they're dealing with; Origin, material, armour, weapons, wings.

Names usually do not tell us everything we might want to know about something. Does John Smith tell us what character or skills he has? Do dog or canis lupus familiaris (literally "the well-known dog descended from the wolf") tell us what it looks like or how it behaves? Does Porsche 911 tell us what kind of machine it is, or even that it is a machine? Not if you don't already know.
Names are labels, not descriptions. They identify something, but they don't explain it. The explanation is something we have to learn along with the name, or look up in an encyclopedia.
Attempting to create names that tell readers that are unfamiliar with your world and the creatures in it what kind of creatures they are is impossible. The names would have to have the length of an encyclopedia entry, at the very least, and even then they wouldn't explain the creature in full, as encyclopedia entries rely on previous knowledge or cross references.
What you need to do is introduce each creature to the reader as it appears, and the reader has to memorize both the name and the information you pass along with it, just as a child has to learn which name refers to which animal and what kind of animal it is ("the dog barks, the chicken has feathers and lays eggs" etc.).
The naming convention itself should be derived from the culture of your world, so you need to do some worldbuilding before you can understand what kind of names the people in your world would give those mechanical creatures. Personally I would assume that the people on any world would go about naming creatures just like humans do: by refering to some distinct feature (the rose, for example, is named for its red color).

"Does John Smith tell us what character or skills he has?" - that he's good at working with metal?

@komodosp "John Smith is a passionate baker with over 15 years of experience in the industry."
